# iphone sdk - segmentedcontrol.tintcolor not working in OS3

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

In my app I have a uisegmentedcontrol in the navigation bar, as the right button item.

the code:

segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.70 green:0.171 blue:0.1 alpha:1.0];

works in OS2 but not OS3...?

ade.

p.s. my base sdk is 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I had to do two things:

1) For views that always had the segmentedcontrol I had to set the tint color after adding the segmentedcontrol to the rightbarbuttonitem and move the code to viewDidAppear (I had it in ViewWillAppear)

2) For views that don't always have the segmentedcontrol it looked ugly using viewDidAppear as it sometimes was showing the segmentedcontrol and then removing it (when it shouldn't be shown at all). So I had to here use viewWillAppear but also set the item to nil in viewDidDisappear

ade.